# Identifying, extracting and counting patterns in sequences

Tags: r, sequence

Hello lovely and nice people of SO, I'm working with a data-frame that contains only two columns one column corresponds to a Unique ID generated by a Virtual Machine and the second column contains a name but this particularly column may also contain the string "ERROR" and the objective is to create a script that will allow us to identify every time the string "ERROR" is found and capture the last and following names around it and also the unique ID assigned to the string "ERROR", to illustrate lets look at the following example:

If I have this data

| ID | NAMES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | James |
| 3 | ERROR |
| 6 | Keras |
| 88 | Kelly |
| 53 | Micheal |
| 55 | ERROR |
| 7 | Cindy |
| 834 | Keras |

Then we would like to have come up with the following list:

| ID | NAMES |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | James-Keras |
| 55 | Micheal-Cindy |

This is because the first string "ERROR" found had an ID of 3 and  was between the names James (before ERROR) and Keras (After ERROR) the next "ERROR"  had an ID of 55 and was between Micheal and Cindy *what if "ERROR" is a the top of the list or the bottom* then we should only include whatever name we find it is ok to have lets say " NA-NAME" is ERROR was found at the top...

But here is where it gets tricky if we ever run into a sequence with consecutive strings "ERROR" we should always use as a "guide" the very last one in descending order for instance:

If I have this data set

| ID | NAMES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | James |
| 3 | ERROR |
| 6 | ERROR |
| 88 | ERROR |
| 53 | Jude |
| 55 | ERROR |
| 7 | Cindy |
| 834 | Keras |

then we will want to have

| ID | NAMES |
| --- | --- |
| 88 | James-Jude |
| 55 | Jude-Cindy |

and this is because the string ERROR was repeated 3 times consecutively but the last one was at ID 88 so that means that we'll take that as a reference and record the names before and after it, another way of seeing this is to view the strings "ERROR" as a block so we'll record the names before and after each block of strings "ERROR"

Thank you so much to everyone that is trying to help me out I'd really appreciate if you can reference a book or functions that could help me out thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may create a function to do this

```
f1 <- function(dat) {

    subdat1 <- subset(dat, !duplicated(with(rle(NAMES == "ERROR"), 
           rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), fromLast = TRUE))
    subdat2 <- subset(dat, !duplicated(with(rle(NAMES == "ERROR"), 
          rep(seq_along(values), lengths))))
    ind <- which(subdat1$NAMES == "ERROR")
    do.call(rbind, lapply(ind[c(TRUE, diff(ind) > 1)], function(i) 
        data.frame(ID = subdat1$ID[i],NAMES = paste(subdat1$NAMES[i-1], 
        subdat2$NAMES[i+1], sep="-"))))
}
```

-testing

```
> f1(df1)
  ID         NAMES
1  3   James-Keras
2 55 Micheal-Cindy
> f1(df2)
  ID      NAMES
1 88 James-Jude
2 55 Jude-Cindy
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 3L, 6L, 88L, 53L, 55L, 7L, 834L), NAMES = c("James", 
"ERROR", "Keras", "Kelly", "Micheal", "ERROR", "Cindy", "Keras"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 3L, 6L, 88L, 53L, 55L, 7L, 834L), NAMES = c("James", 
"ERROR", "ERROR", "ERROR", "Jude", "ERROR", "Cindy", "Keras")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so so much you have no Idea how much I appreciate your help I'm just an R student and I am trying to push myself with these challenges and sometimes I can't so I am forever thankful to have you akrun helping from wherever you're thanks a million these people on SO can be so Nast sometimes thanks for being so kind to me thank you so much, may I please ask you what books or blogs would you personally recommend to me to study R and gain more skills? Thank you so much again

Comment: @R_Student Thank you for the kind words.  I would say practice (daily at least spend 10-15 mins in solving questions) and make mistakes, debug, and find answers by yourself makes a lot of difference in learning.  You can learn the theoretical and some common syntax from a lot of R resources available in the web.  Ultimately, you have to do the practice.  Also, answering in SO makes a huge difference as well as it makes you think in ways you may never have earlier..